# Is it a good practice to store C structures on the stack?

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Tiny structures that represent some variables in the calculations should definitely be stored on the stack, but what about more common structures like this one:

```
typedef struct {
  int number_of_nodes;
  int number_of_edges;
  char *adjacency_matrix;
} graph_t;
```

For now I store graph_t structures on the stack:

```
graph_t graph1 = read_graph(PATH);
graph_t graph2 = new_graph(graph1.number_of_nodes);
func(&graph1, &graph2);
```

Is there any reason to keep this structure in heap memory instead of the stack?

```
graph_t *graph1 = read_graph(PATH);
graph_t *graph2 = new_graph(graph1->number_of_nodes);
func(graph1, graph2);
```

Comment: The stack is memory too...

Comment: Also, no, if the structs are local to the variable, and you don't need to return pointers to them, then definitely don't mallocate memory for them, just declare them with automatic storage duration.

Comment: @H2CO3 "mallocate"? love it.

Comment: @feralin Definitely. Pairs nicely with "free". :)

Comment: For structures that small, unless you're going to define ginormous arrays of them, they can be allocated on the stack (as automatic variables) and be passed by value without qualms.  For very large structures or large arrays of a structure, then you should think carefully about stack vs dynamic allocation.

Comment: @H2CO3. 1) "The stack is memory too...": oh, I meant heap memory. 2) "Also, no, if the structs are local to the variable, and you don't need to return pointers to them": I always allocate memory in the caller function, like in the code above.

Comment: @kermzyxer Then you have my answer :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "and be passed by value without qualms": what about passing pointer to an automatic variable, if I need to make changes?

Comment: You can pass stack values as a pointer without qualms as well.

Comment: @kermzyxer That *can be* even cheaper (unless `sizeof struct < sizeof struct *`).

Answer (score 1):

You have probably been reading older textbooks from back when the stack was a few kilobytes and "stack overflow" was a common error, not a web site.

The stack on a modern PC will be several MB by default; on a Linux box, try `ulimit -s`. Last I checked on my netbook, I could write all of Shakespeare's tragedies to the stack without any difficulties. Yes, there are data sets easily bigger than that, but you describe your structs are relatively small, so you can probably fit tens of thousands (if not millions) of your structs on the stack without any problem at all.

As mentioned in the comments, writing structs directly to the stack also has the usual conveniences of not needing to allocate or free memory.